# view does not appear, only data appears

Tags: laravel

i want to passing data to view

my controller

```
public function create()
{
    $maxcode=Product::selectRaw('MAX(RIGHT(product_code, 3)) as max')->first();
    $prx='P2018-';
    if($maxcode->count()>0)
    {
            $tmp = ((int)$maxcode->max)+1;
            $newcode = $prx.sprintf("%03s", $tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        $newcode = $prx."P2018-001";
    }

    return $newcode;

    return view('product.create', $newcode);
}
```

my view

```
...other code...

@foreach($newcode as $nc)
    {{$nc->newcode}}
@endforeach

---other code...
```

the code works well, but the only results appear, the other code on the view does not work.

someone might be able to help me

Comment: `return $newcode;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove return $newcode;

return view('product.create')->with('newcode',$newcode);

**$newcode** variable is not an array, you can not use foreach.

use **{{$newcode}}** in blade to display value of variable.

Answer (score 0):

remove `return $newcode;` line and change your return function like this,

```
return view('product.create', compact('newcode'));
```

Comment: @codespark $newcode is not an array or collection in your controller so you can't use foreach on it.

Comment: @codespark just remove foreach and just put `{{$newcode}}` in your view.

Comment: the result is still the same

Comment: Quite strange problem then

Comment: @codespark I've saying the same thing as in above answer you didn't understand :D